# F# numeric type casting

Tags: f#, type-conversion

I'm writing a program in which I have to validate some input of type obj into numeric types. Basically, I'm looking to write functions

```
validateint   : obj -> int option
validatefloat : obj -> float option
... and so on
```

In itself this isn't a problem, for example, for example I got something like:

```
let validateint x =
    match x with
        | y when y.GetType() = typeof<int>          -> y :?> int                 |> Some
        | y when y.GetType() = typeof<float>        -> y :?> float        |> int |> Some
        | y when y.GetType() = typeof<System.Int16> -> y :?> System.Int16 |> int |> Some
        /// ...more numeric cases
        | _                                         -> None
```

However, after writing similar code for validateint I thought to factor out a function that takes the casting function as an input, something like:

```
let validatenumeric cast x =
    match x with
        | y when y.GetType() = typeof<int>          -> y :?> int          |> cast |> Some
        | y when y.GetType() = typeof<float>        -> y :?> float        |> cast |> Some
        | y when y.GetType() = typeof<System.Int16> -> y :?> System.Int16 |> cast |> Some
        /// ...more numeric cases
        | _                                         -> None
```

and then defining

```
let validateint = validatenumeric int
let validatefloat = validatenumeric float
...
```

However, this doesn't work because F# basically infers the type of cast to be int -> 'a and then the 2nd and later match cases are typed incorrectly. I guess I could sort of avoid this by putting in an extra cast for every numeric type to a float, but that feels like an ugly hack. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you do not need to re-implement the functionality yourself. The `System.Convert` type in .NET already provides an operation that tries to convert any input to a specified type and fails if the conversion cannot be done.

```
let validateNumeric<'T> input =
  try Some(System.Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof<'T>) :?> 'T)
  with _ -> None
```

Here is a sample F# Interactive output:

```
> validateNumeric<int> (box 1.1);;
val it : int option = Some 1
> validateNumeric<float> "1.1";;
val it : float option = Some 1.1
> validateNumeric<float> "xxx";;
val it : float option = None
```

An unfortunate thing is that there is no method that would not throw an exception - so if you need to convert thousands of values, this might be too slow for you.

Comment: Thanks. As a follow up question, is writing this function without type annotations something that just isn't possible in F#, or wouldn't be possible in order functional languages either. I'm trying to understand why exactly this function fails (both in the original form as well as when for example adding the annotation ^a -> 'b when ^a : (static member op_Explicit : ^a -> 'b)).

Comment: @Bram In F#, you cannot directly pass a generic function as an argument (so that you can call it on different types). This is possible in some other languages - and you can achieve this in F# too but you'd have to pass it as an interface implemented by an object expression (so it gets all a bit ugly).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a generic type, try this

```
let validate<'a, 'b> (cast: 'a -> 'b) (x: 'a) =
    try
        cast x |> Some
    with _ -> None

let a = validate int "123"
let b = validate int 1.23
let c = validate float "abc"
let d = validate<obj, decimal> Convert.ToDecimal (null :> obj)
let e = validate<string, DateTime> Convert.ToDateTime "2013-9-21"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works just as well as the previous answer, but since I had to pick only one, I chose the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
open System
let validateint =function
  |(x:obj) when x=null->None
  | :? int as i->Some(i)
  | :? float as f->Some(f|>int)
  | :? string as s->Int32.TryParse(s)|>function |true,x->Some(x)|_->None
  //| :? ...
  |_->None
```